# Handle is not initialized error

Tags: .net, entity-framework

I have a wpf app and I'm using MVVM.  I've bound a datagrid directly to the viewmodel for update, add and delete.  There are no buttons for these actions.  it all works great through bound properties.  Except for one issue.

if a user close the view with uncommitted changes in the datagrid I try and capture this in the descructor of the ViewModel. Which then calls the ADD or update method.  But when the

```
Context.SaveChanges();
```

is called i get a "Handle is not initialized" inner exception.

The Datacontext is not Null.  I create the datacontext in the ViewModels base class and close it in the viewmodels base class destructor.  Stepping through the code shows the base class destructor has not yet been called.

Below is my stack trace.

```
 at System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.Update(IEntityStateManager stateManager, IEntityAdapter adapter)
 at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityAdapter.Update(IEntityStateManager entityCache)
 at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChanges(SaveOptions options)
 at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChanges()
 at InspectorGeneral.ViewModel.VMItemList.Update(ItemsList obj)
 at InspectorGeneral.ViewModel.VMItemList.Modify(ItemsList obj)
 at InspectorGeneral.ViewModel.VMItemList.set_SelectedListItem(ItemsList value)
 at InspectorGeneral.ViewModel.VMItemList.Finalize()
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction why this line of code is failing.

regards

Answer (score 3):

I tried to execute a database call in [Finalize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.finalize.aspx), and also got this same error.

Taking it out of [Finalize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.finalize.aspx) was the only option.

Comment: I can see why this would be a problem but do you know is there an in-depth explanation of what happens when a database call in finalize is attempted?