# Update Entity Framework property when different property in model is changed

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, observablecollection, inotifypropertychanged

I have an Entity Framework model

```
public partial class Product
{
    public Product()
    {
        this.Designs = new HashSet<Design>();
    }

    public int BookingProductId { get; set; }
    public System.Guid BookingId { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }

    public virtual Booking Booking { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Design> Designs { get; set; }
}
```

...in which I would like to update the Price property in response to a new Design being added to the Product. I've tried to follow this example:

[How can I change an Entity Framework ICollection to be an ObservableCollection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17073114/how-can-i-change-an-entity-framework-icollection-to-be-an-observablecollection)

so my class reads as follows:

```
public partial class Product : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public Product()
    {
        this.Designs = new ObservableCollection<Design>();
    }

    public int BookingProductId { get; set; }
    public System.Guid BookingId { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }

    public virtual Booking Booking { get; set; }
    public virtual ObservableCollection<Design> Designs { get; set; }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

but if I add a new Design to the Product as so

```
product.Designs.Add(new Design());
```

then the NotifyPropertyChanged method is never fired. Does anyone know why???

Thanks in advance

Comment: Based on some answers to other questions, I wonder if you should look at the `INotifyCollectionChanged` event.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NotfiyPropertyChanged will only called when you set the whole collection and not the included items.

This is a workaround for the problme:

```
public partial class Product : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public Product()
    {
        this.Designs = new ObservableCollection<Design>();
        this.Designs.CollectionChanged += ContentCollectionChanged;
    }

    public void ContentCollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // This will get called when the collection is changed
        // HERE YOU CAN ALSO FIRE THE PROPERTY CHANGED 
    }

    public int BookingProductId { get; set; }
    public System.Guid BookingId { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }

    public virtual Booking Booking { get; set; }
    public virtual ObservableCollection<Design> Designs { get; set; }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's great , thanks very much. I've noticed also now that the ContentCollectionChanged event is fired when I retrieve the product object from the database and .Include the designs, which makes sense but I wonder if there is any way to differentiate this from when I .Add(new Design()); ???

Comment: Normally you do not have to that, let say you are using MVVM pattern and you have bound your collection to a ListBox.
The ListBox will fire this event for example SelectedItem(s)Changed etc.

Comment: Not sure I understand that...Can I rephrase? I've retrieved a Product and associated Designs from the DB: var product = this.GetDbSet<BookingProduct>().Include(c => c.BookingDesigns).Single(c => c.BookingProductId == bookingProductId); At this point each time a Design is added to the product the ContentCollectionChanged is fired. Then I wish to add a new Design as so...product.Designs.Add(new Design()); and the ContentCollectionChanged is also fired. It is at this point I wish to perform an action on the Price property of Product rather than when I retrieve from DB. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 4):

NotifyPropertyChanged never fires because adding another element to your Designs collection doesn't actually change any Product's properties. If you want to track changes within the collection itself, it should implement [INotifyCollectionChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.collections.specialized.inotifycollectionchanged%28v=vs.90%29) interface. ObservableCollection already implements that, so you can simply handle CollectionChanged event.